# How to make SAXParser ignore escape codes

Tags: java, saxparser, html-escape-characters

I am writing a Java program to read and XML file, actually an iTunes library which is XML plist format.
I have managed to get round most obstacles that this format throws up except when it encounters text containing the `&`. The XLM file represents this ampersand as `&#38;` and I can only manage to read the text following the `&#38;` in any particular section of text.

Is there a way to disable detection of escape codes? I am using SAXParser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something fishy about what you are trying to do.

If the file format you are trying to parse contains bare ampersand (`&`) characters then it is *not* well-formed XML.  Ampersands are represented as character entities (e.g. `&amp;`) in well-formed XML.

- If it is really supposed to be real XML, then there is a bug in whatever wrote / generated the file.
- If it is not supposed to be real XML (i.e. those ampersands are not a mistake), then you probably shouldn't by trying to parse it using an XML parser.

---

Ah, I see.  The XML is actually correctly encoded, but you didn't get the SO markup right.

It would appear that your real problem is that your `characters(...)` callback is being called separately for the text before the `&#38;`, for the (decoded) `&#38;`, and finally for the text after the `&#38;`.  You simply have to have to deal with this by joining the text chunks back together.

The javadoc for [`ContentHandler.characters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) says this:

> *"The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks ..."*.

Comment: The XLM file is in Apples XML plist format and the & is represented by &#38; Sorry, I forgot to mention that in my message!.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best general solution for escape characters, but I only had to take into account new lines so it was easy to just check for \n.

You could check for the backslash \ only to check for all escape characters or in your case &, although I think others will come with more elegant solutions.

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) 
{
    String elementData = new String(ch, start, length);
    boolean elementDataContainsNewLine = (elementData.indexOf("\n") != -1);

    if (!elementDataContainsNewLine) 
    {
        //do what you want if it is no new line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an excerpt for us? Is the file itunes-generated? If so, it sounds like a bug in iTunes to me, that forgot to encode the ampersand correctly. I would not be surprised: they clearly didn't get XML in the first place, their schema of `<name>[key]</name><string>[value]</string>` must make the XML inventors puke.

You might want to use a different, more robust, parser. SAX is great as long as the file is well-formed. I do however not know how robust dom4j and jdom are. Just give them a try. For python, I know that I would recomment `ElementTree` or `BeautifulSoup` which are very robust.

Also have a look at http://code.google.com/p/xmlwise/ which I found *mentioned here in stackoverflow* (did you use search?).

**Update**: (as per updated question) You *need* to understand the role of entities in XML and thus SAX. They by default a separate nodes, just like text nodes. So you will likely need to join them with adjacent text nodes to get the full value. Do you use a DTD in your parser? Using a proper DTD - with entity definitions - can help parsing a lot, as it can contain mappings from entities such as `&amp;` to the characters they represent `&`, and the parser may be able to do the merging for you. (At least the python XML-pull parser I like to use for large files does when materializing subtrees.)

Answer (score -1):

I am parsing the below string using SAXParser

```
<xml>
<FirstTag>&amp;&lt;</FirstTag>
<SecondTag>test</SecondTag>
</xml>
I want the same string to be retained but it is getting converted to below
<xml>
<FirstTag>&<</FirstTag>
<SecondTag>test</SecondTag>
<xml>
Here is my code. How can I avoid this being converted?
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();  
        values = handler.getValues();
        saxParser.parse(x, handler);
```