# SAX parsing and special characters

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser

I want to parse some data from an xml file using SAX parser. My xml is as follows:

```
<categories>
 <cat>Pies &amp; past</cat>
 <cat>Fruits</cat>
</categories>
```

In order to parse this data I extend DefaultHandler.

The output after parsing is:

```
cat 1 = Pies

cat 2 = &

cat 3 = past

cat 4 = Fruits
```

Why is this happening instead of getting:

```
cat 1 = Pies & past

cat 2 = Fruits
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770097/how-to-make-saxparser-ignore-escape-codes

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters#answer-4567652) for an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that you are treating each call to `characters` as delivering the complete text for a `cat` element. You should code your handler so that successive calls to `characters` accumulate the text, and you only capture it on the `endElement` event:

```
public class CatHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private StringBuilder chars = new StringBuilder();

    public void startElement(String uri, String lName, String qName, Attributes a)
    {
        final String name = qName == null ? lName : qName;
        if ("cat".equals(name)) {
            chars.setLength(0);
        } else . . .
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String lName, String qName) {
        final String name = qName == null ? lName : qName;
        if ("cat".equals(name)) {
            String catName = chars.toString();
            // do something with cat name
        } else . . .
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        chars.append(ch, start, length);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `characters()` method doesn't have to return the complete text element. Rather you should collate the text available in each `characters()` call, and concatenate these upon the corresponding `endElement()` call.

From [the doc](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

> The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character
>   data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single
>   chunk, *or they may split it into several chunks*

(my emphasis)