# SAX parser; Bug when reading Special Characters

Tags: java, xml, parsing, character, sax

In my XML file, I have a tag that has the special char

```
<journal>Universit&auml;t Trier</journal>
```

When I run the SAX Parser, I realized that it will divide the String into 2

```
String 1: Universit
String 2: &auml;t Trier
```

However I need to read the content as one whole String in order to properly store in Database. I can't have it split into 2 String. Why does SAX Parser do this anyway?

Following method is part of the SAX parser that does the Reading

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException 
{
                       ...
}
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336140/sax-parsing-and-special-characters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770097/how-to-make-saxparser-ignore-escape-codes

Comment: Could you flag the answer as accepted ? You should also clean you other posts and provide some follow up. TIA

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug.

It is simply the way SAX is designed, and it needs to be this way in order to have any possibility of dealing with mixed content.

Without mixed content it's actually quite simple.

What you need to do is to recombine the fragments in your own implementation of the SAX `ContentHandler` interface.

Typically this means initializing a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` field in the `startElement` method, appending to it in the `characters` method and converting it to a `String` in the `endElement` method.